# SaltStack master/minion to administrate my database that is inside a container

Tags: docker, salt-stack

I have been learning Docker for a while and been trying to migrate some of the SaltStack states that I have made for previously provisioning all my systems to partly (?) using docker. However once I have my database within a container how can I administrate it like I would with a normal locally install database on the host box?

The setup in detail: I have a master server (`salt-master`) and a couple of minions (`web-nginx` and `web-db`) each deployed with their respective containers and stacks. The `web-db` is running the `postgres` container. For completeness `web-nginx` has the application source code being served through an `nginx` container with `php-fpm` container processing. All the containers are the officials from the docker official repositories.

**Now the issue** is how can I use my salt states that would manage the adding/remove of users on the `postgres` database? As far as I can see no-one has asked this and in "similar" questions everyone has assumed that the host machine is the master--which in my case is not true, the master is remote and the host machine is a minion itself. So to clarify `salt-master > web-db > postgres(container)` where as I think salt can only do `master > minion` and I need something like `master > minion > minion-delegate`.

**Anyone know of a way for me to do this?**

As an aside I am aware that as my `web-db` box is an isolated instance I can probably stop this pain and manage that server like I would normally (without docker). This would solve my problem but I wouldn't mind hearing some solutions for using it within a container.

Comment: Any news at this?

Comment: Sorry no update on this. I took the dead thread as a sign that maybe I should just provision my box as normal using salt instead of trying to use docker for this. That is, its isolated to only run Postgres so why use docker on it also.